# Trouble updating value of captions in userform labels when change occurs in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a userform which has a number of conditional settings which should apply.
I have x number of labels, all refering to a given cell value in worksheet 2.

I have everythijng working properly, however I need to re-run the UserForm to apply changes to the label values. Now, I'm using

```vb
Me.Repaint
```

at the end of the UserForm code.

I've added the folowing code to VBA mODULE "ThisWorkbook":

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ws2")

    If Target.Address(False, False) = ws2.Cells("C8").Value Then
        MsgBox "Value Changed!"
    End If

End Sub
```

However I can not get this to work. I can get it work by only refering to a single cell in the first worksheet:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(False, False) = "A2" Then
        MsgBox "Value Changed!"
            'repaint userform!
    End If
End Sub
```

I would of course replace the messagebox with a Me.Repaint or something similar to repaint my form if any value changes.

Is there a guru here, which could help me resolve this issue? I want my userform Label caption values to update if the value of cell C8 in ws2 changes.

Comment: I would debug this by setting a break point at `If Target.Address(False, False) = ws2.Cells("C8").Value Then`. Make a change to your C8 cell and ...
1) See if the event is firing at all
2) Check the value that is in ws2.Cells("C8").Value and Target.Address to see why/if they don't match. I'm guessing Target.Address has some `$` characters that your C8 cell value does not have...

Comment: I added two string variables and toggled a breakpoint for my If-statement. As it turned out, the values were not equal as you ointed out.
Also, I noticed that Sh were in fact a worksheet name. I used this and made it work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code was the result of debugging, and answered my question. Thanks to @Dean for helping out.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Sh.Name = "ws2" Then
        If Target.Address(False, False) = "C8" Then

            MsgBox "Value Changed!"

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```